# Internet Explorer won't display range slider or update CSS with jquery

Tags: jquery, css, html, internet-explorer, range

I have a HTML5 range slider, and a div `id="text_output"` above it. The div starts off with css `display: none;`, and I update the css to `display: block;` when the slider is moved. I also update the text in the div to display the slider value. Simple, right?

Try as I might though, I'm having trouble getting IE to display ranges and updating the div (I'm testing on version 11). I have added `<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge">` because it was rendering as IE7 by default when I checked in the development tools menu (what's with that?!). However, IE still won't display a range slider, instead opting to show some sort of `textarea`. Here's a minimal working html document that can be pasted, and gives the desired output in Firefox and Chromium, and reproduces the problem as described when accessed from my webserver by my PC and also a colleague's PC.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <style>
            #text_output {
                display: none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div id="text_output">Blah</div>
    <input id="range_test" name="score" type="range" min="1" max="3" value="2">

    <script>
$("#range_test").on("input", function(){
    //note that plus '+' casts as an int. Otherwise switch block uses === type comparison
    //on slider value (which is passed as a string) and fails
    switch( +$("#range_test").val() ){
        case 1:
            $("#text_output").css("display", "block");
            $("#text_output").text("text1");
            break;
        case 2:
            $("#text_output").css("display", "block");
            $("#text_output").text("text2");
            break;
        case 3:
            $("#text_output").css("display", "block");
            $("#text_output").text("text3");
            break;
    }
});

    </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

I have tried pasting the css generated by Daniel Stern's [range.css](http://danielstern.ca/range.css/#/) inline in the style block just in case it was a style issue, but that hasn't changed anything.

Anyone got any ideas on why this doesn't work in IE?

Comment: Is `.on("input"` valid? Wouldn't it be `.on("change"` ?

Comment: You want `.on("input"` if you want to the change to occur without releasing the mouse. `.on("change"` only fires the event when you let go. I tested it anyway; it doesn't seem to make a difference to IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escher,

I tested this locally and the doc defaulted to an older IE version. If you move the meta tag before your script include, see below, this shall sort out your IE Version issue. As for your other issue, unfortunately I can't reproduce on my current PC - I have no access to an IE version supporting rage sliders. I suspect your issue may be related to the meta tag being in the wrong place.

```
     <head>

        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <style>
            #text_output {
                display: none;
           }
        </style>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    </head>
```

Comment: Well spotted; the tag order fixed the range display issue!

Answer (score 1):

It's working fine for me in IE11 if I replace `on("input"` by `on("change"`.

http://codepen.io/jeremythille/pen/NPzVXb

`on("input"` does not trigger the `console.log("changed")`, but `on("change"` does. And the value keeps getting updated, even if I don't release the mouse button when sliding.

**Edit** : you could strongly improve performance by caching  `$textOutput = $("#text_output")` for instance.

Comment: Whoah! I just tested it locally on a Windows machine, and it works, but from a webserver it doesn't. Same comment applies to `on("change"` vs `on("input"` - there's a difference between file access and webserver access. What gives?!

Comment: BTW, on my IE11 your codepen doesn't update `#text_output` display property, it seems. Nothing happens when the slider is moved.

Comment: That's weird. All I can say is that it works fine on my IE11. I can see "text1", "text2" and "text3" displaying as I move the slider.

Comment: It turns out that your codepen still used `on("input"` when I accessed it, and this caused it not to work. You are right, `on("change"` works for IE both locally and via the web, but `on("input"` only works locally for IE. `on("input"` works for Chrome & FF under Windows & Linux, but `on("change"` does not update when sliding. I'll ask a separate question for that. I'm going to accept @ScottMac's answer because technically he solved the range display problem, but +1 for all the jquery advice, it really helped clarify my thinking.

Comment: Fair enough. No problem for the help.